# Read files from a folder with names don't contains a string, using PySpark

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, glob

I have a folder with files similar to -

```
./env_california_0100.xml
./env_california_0200.xml
./env_california_0300.xml
./env_california_0400.xml
./env_0100.xml
./env_0200.xml
./env_0300.xml
./env_0400.xml
```

using pyspark, if I want to read files whose names contain the string 'california', then I would use

```
df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","someTag").load("/some_folder/*california*.xml")
```

But how to read files which do not have the string 'california'?

Comment: Try `!(*california*)*.xml` (untested)

Comment: `/some_folder/*california*.xml` is a *glob* pattern. Why `regex` tag?

Comment: @pault ` !(*california*)*.xml ` did not work

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew How would we use glob in PySpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use glob to extract the list of file, then unpack that list in the load call:

```
   .load(*glob.glob( "/some_folder/*[!california]*.xml"))
```

Because we can load multiple file like this: `.load(path1,path2,....)`

Comment: This will work wih glob why don't you use glob to extract the list of files? Then load them one by one in for loop?

Comment: Do you mean, read into RDDs? When I use glob with SparkSession, it says - input should be a path. Can you give me sample of what you are suggesting?

Comment: It turns out that load accept more then one argument so just unpack the list returned by glob check my edits,

Comment: ```df= spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","someTag")\
        .load(*glob.glob("/some_folder/*[!California]*.xml"))```    
    
```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o341.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: /some_folder/env_0100.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Comment: This answers your question as you can see,  it's trying to load file `env_001.xml`, you should ask another question why it fails to load this file axactly, do you agree?

Comment: I can load the file directly by specifying the file-path and read it, which means, the XML is fine. But when i use the glob suggested, i got the error I posted. Sorry for confusion, the exact error is below: It throws error that it is not able to find the file with California, which is weird because we want to exclude it.

Comment: ```df= spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","someTag")\ .load(*glob.glob("/some_folder/*[!California]*.xml")) Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o341.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: /some_folder/env_california_0100.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html```

Comment: When you print the list of file retrieved by glob do you see this file? In it?

Comment: Just to make sure try to pass two paths as argument to load method, to see if they are both loaded normally